# Passing values by reference in multithread programming

Tags: python, multithreading, pass-by-reference

I've wrote a program that uses the threading module to create a thread that add 1 to a previously defined variable, but, once the program is terminated, the variable's value is still the same. I've tried this:

```
from threading import Thread

def plus_one(var):
        return var + 1

var = 0

print var

my_adder = Thread(target = plus_one, args = (var, ))
var = my_adder.start()
my_adder.join()

print var
```

But it doesn't works...what should i do? I've already search for some information but it's all quite confusing..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Python "variables"

In python, you don't have 'variables', and you can't 'pass by reference' or 'pass by value'.  You have 'names', which get bound to values in memory.  Those values can change, or the name can change. For instance:

```
>>> x = 21
>>> y = x
>>> y
21

>>> x = 100
>>> y
21
```

When you create a function, any name that's value changes is treated as a new name altogether, and doesn't point to the outside one:

```
>>> x = 21
>>> def do(a):
        x = a + 100  # x here is a new local name, since you've assigned to it.
>>> do(x)
>>> x
21
```

However, if all your doing is *reading* the name, then python will leave you access to read the variable from the parent 'scope':

```
>>> x = 21
>>> def p():
        print (x)

>>> p()
21
```

This is the first problem with your code.  The way to do it is to use a name which is defined globally, and tell the function to use that global name:

```
>>> x = 21
>>> def do():
        global x
        x = 41
>>> do()
>>> x
41
```

(In python 3, you can use `nonlocal` rather than `global` to access a non-global name from a parent scope).

When you were returning a value, you need to assign the name to that value in the same scope as where it's defined.

## Mutable and immutable names:

If you bind a name to something like a number, a tuple, or a string, then the value is `immutable`.  You can't change it.  So every time you say `x = 1` and then `x = 21`, you're not changing the value of x, you're re-binding x to point at a new value.  That's why the `y = x` example y didn't change.  It was still bound to the old value.  The value didn't change, but `x` now pointed at a new one.

However, not all things in python are immutable.  Lists, dicts, objects, etc, aren't immutable.  So:

```
>>> x = [100]
>>> def do(l):
        l[0] = 50
>>> do(x)
>>> x
[50]
```

Also:

```
>>> x = [21]
>>> y = x
>>> x[0] = 50
>>> y
[50]
```

This can be used to 'pass values by reference', if you really need to.  However, if you're abusing it, it's usually a good sign that somehow the structure of the code is wrong.

## Threads and variable access

What you were doing was returning a new value, but not assigning it anywhere.  The thread `.start()` method doesn't work that way.  The reason is that if it did, then you would be blocking the current thread (that actually binds the name to the new value) waiting for the one which is returning the new value to set it to, which would rather miss the point of threads.

You can use the methods above to get around this.

One thing you really need to be aware of is that variables accessed from multiple threads can be rather scary, with things not behaving quite right, if multiple threads try to access the same values at the same time.

Here is a very good article about 'locks', and how to be safe working with threads.

http://effbot.org/zone/thread-synchronization.htm

Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

Python passes only objects by reference, scalar values are passed by values. SO, if you define a class

```
class IntWrapper(object):
    val = 1

def incr(obj)
    obj.val += 1
```

That will work

Comment: If multiple threads will increment the same counter, it needs to be protected by a lock.

Answer (score 0):

for that you should initialize your variable as 0

at the time of declaration  also change your variable name

because var is a itself keyword  so it is good to use another variable

Comment: *var* is not keyword in Python

Comment: @volcano yup but its a `function`

Comment: ----> 1 var

NameError: name 'var' is not defined

Comment: @volcano oops mistook it for `vars`